# Would it be relevant to ask on Meta whether or not a question belong to Stack Overflow before asking it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, meta

As the title says.

I've been looking around for information in the Tour, the Help Center and the ["participate in meta" privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta), but so far I wasn't able to tell for sure whether or not it would be relevant.

Though I believe that checking whether or not a question truly has its place before posting is a better move than posting it right away, I'm not totally sure if asking for confirmation is allowed on Meta.

Comment: "would it be relevant on meta to ask a question about asking a question on meta about asking a question on the main site"

Comment: @KevinB That's literally what I thought 4 minutes ago.

Comment: I have to admit I found it most efficient to take my best guess and if it's wrong ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: @KevinB that is obviously a question for meta.meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @visibleman Or is it...?

Comment: @visibleman Your comment belongs on meta.meta.meta.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

These questions are quite on-topic here on Meta- You're asking about the site, specifically what belongs on it.

Be sure to tag it with [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation), as if your question doesn't belong here, people will likely suggest where it does belong if it will fit elsewhere on the network.

Also be sure to give us a good idea what your question is. You don't have to give us the full question you plan to post, but enough detail to know what sort of question you're asking is important.

And, most importantly, try checking through some of the previous such questions to see if that answers the question you plan to ask. Could save you time and trouble.